# I can't get my call to boto3's CloudWatch client get_metric_data() call to work for OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, opensearch

I'm looking to use boto3 to the get_metric_data() method to get Cloudwatch metrics from the OpenSearch service.  I'm looking to retrieve the number of DeletedRecords.  If you could add any extra information about the Dimensions key and how that works generally (as I have more metrics to pick pick up after this) it would be really helpful.

This is my code:

```
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')

response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
                MetricDataQueries =
                [
                        {
                                'Id': 'cloudwatch_test_response',
                                'MetricStat':
                                        {
                                                'Metric':
                                                {
                                                        'Namespace': 'ES/OpenSearchService',
                                                        'MetricName': 'DeletedDocuments',
                                                        'Dimensions':
                                                        [
                                                                {
                                                                        'Name': 'ClientId',
                                                                        'Value': 'ABCDEFGHIJK'

                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        'Name': 'DomainName',
                                                                        'Value': 'samplename-poc'


                                                                },
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                'Period': 300,
                                                'Stat': 'Average',
                                                'Unit': 'Count'

                                        },

                                'ReturnData': True,
                                'AccountId': 'ABCD-EFGH-IJK'
                        },

                ],
                StartTime = datetime(2023, 4, 12),
                EndTime = datetime(2023, 4, 13),
                ScanBy = 'TimestampDescending',

                )
```

This is the message I'm getting in my response:

```
{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'cloudwatch_test_response', 'Label': 'DeletedDocuments', 'Timestamps': [], 'Values': [], 
'StatusCode': 'Forbidden', 'Messages': [{'Code': 'Forbidden', 'Value': 'Access denied when getting data - please check 
that this account and the requested metric account are linked'}]}], 'Messages': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 
'XXXXXX-ff6d-409f-86f0-967d1bc21426', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 
'XXXXXX-ff6d-409f-86f0-967d1bc21426', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '771', 'date': 
'Tue, 18 Apr 2023 22:17:37 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the metric data in us-east-1 and are the account-id of the boto3 authentication and inside the request the same? Usually you don't need to specify the accountid when requesting data from CW.